# WSO2 Iterate mediator does not maintain order even though sequential="true"

Tags: iterator, wso2-esb

I have scenario like ,

1. Reading unreaded gmail which contains attachment(ie Images)
2. for iterating over attachment, i have used Iterate Mediator in WSO2 EI
3. Inserting those each image attachment to Salesforce File Object.

Process works fine. my question here is **iterate mediator doesn't maintain the order in which attachment presented in email body even though setting sequential="true"** .

```
<iterate continueParent="true" description="MailIterator" expression="//parts" id="listUnread" sequential="true">
    <target>
        <sequence>
            <property expression="//filename/text()" name="AttachedFileName" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <property expression="substring-after(get-property('AttachedFileName'),'.')" name="Attachmentextension" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
            <filter description="check emailSubject" regex="jpg|jpeg|png|gif|webp|tiff|tif|psd|raw|bmp|dib|heif|heic|indd|ind|jp2" source="get-property('Attachmentextension')">
                <then>
                    <property description="emailAttachmentId" expression="//attachmentId/text()" name="uri.var.attachmentId" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                    <log level="custom">
                        <property expression="get-property('AttachedFileName')" name="=====ValidAttachmentFileName===="/>
                        <property expression="get-property('uri.var.attachmentId')" name="====emailAttachmentId====="/>
                    </log>
                     <!-- Salesforce file object insert process done here  -->
                </then>
                <else>
                    <log level="custom">
                        <property expression="fn:concat('Image format. FileName is:',get-property('AttachedFileName'))" name="===Invalid"/>
                    </log>
                </else>
            </filter>
        </sequence>
    </target>
</iterate>
```

**It process all attachment in some other order which is different from email body attachment order**. Kindly anyone clarify this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This might have to do with your "salesforce processing". Do you do a (blocking) call or send there by any chance?

Comment: Hi @ophychius,
Thanks for your response. I am using call Mediator in order to insert image into Salesforce File Object like below. 
**<property expression="fn:concat($ctx:instance_url,'/services/data/v47.0/sobjects/ContentDocumentLink/')" name="uri.var.ContentDocumentLink" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
                        <call description="ContentDocumentlinkEndpoint">
                            <endpoint>
                                <http method="post" uri-template="{uri.var.ContentDocumentLink}"/>
                            </endpoint>
                        </call>**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use call mediator with option blocking="true" to perform synchronous calls

Comment: Hi @Jean,
 Yes you are right, call mediator with option blocking="true" satisfy my requirement, but it affects performance by taking too long time. anyway thanks for your useful answer. Let me know if any possibilities for this low performance improvement.

Comment: I don't really see how, in order to improve performance, calls should be operated in parallel with asynchronous calls, but the answers arrive in disorder, perhaps by specifying a call identifier to be retrieved from the answer so as to reorder?